# Google App Engine imagettfbbox(): Invalid font filename

Tags: php, google-app-engine, imagettftext

The `imagettfbbox()` function works on localhost but when I deploy it I get file not found for the font. I tried different `app.yaml` configurations for the font directory and used different directories but nothing works.

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  The request was aborted because it exceeded the maximum execution time. in /ajaxLoad.php on line 82

Comment: Please show us a minimal failing example (working on the dev_appserver but failing when deployed) with app.yaml, exact directory structure, and details of the imagettfbbox call. It's impossible to debug your problem without such complete and minimal-failing-case details.